# VHDL: signal delay without using clock

Tags: vhdl, fpga, i2c

I am developing an I2C slave driver in VHDL for a Cyclone II FPGA, without using any external clock but the SCL signal. When the master (a PIC24 microcontroller) send a byte ending with a '1', the circuit generate an ACK condition on the falling edge of SCL and the master interprets this state as an 'I2C start condition'. I believe that I have to delay the acknowledgement of some nanoseconds in order to avoid this wrong condition. I have used 'after' and 'wait for' statement but they do not seem to work. I was also thinking to use a chain of inverter, but I have no idea how to use it.

Can anyone help me to create inverter chain, to use VHDL statements in the right way or to figure out somehow this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have finally solved the problem. I used a chain of inverter and it is working perfectly. 
I don't need a precise delay, since I just want to avoid the wrong start condition. 
I found this code in a post of another blog:

signal chain: std_logic_vector(30 downto 0);
attribute syn_keep: boolean;
attribute syn_keep of chain: signal is true;

genchain:
for i in 1 to 30 generate
  chain(i) <= not chain(i-1);
end generate;
chain(0) <= not chain(30);

Comment: Please just don't do that, it's only asking for trouble and at worst you even think you learned something. Lear how to do it properly with synchronous design. You can use set_min_delay to set the minimum delay, the tools will insert what is needed/use routing, but even then you need the reference clock.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make design like that without any clock (clock from I2C is not suitable for this).  Command like 'after' and 'wait for' are for simulation only, and are not synthesizable.

I cannot directly answer your question, because it depends on your specific design. You probably need to implement some counter.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. So, in VHDL, is it impossible to delay a signal with an inverter chain, either?

Comment: Probably, but I think it wouldn't be fully predictable, and it's also complicated. Also, you will have issues with synchronization. It's best to use clock.

Answer (score 0):

A delay made with an inverter chain will vary between FPGAs depending on things like temperature and age of FPGA.

An inverter chain is simply a signal inverted several times - the propagation delay of each gate determines the total signal delay. Each time you run a place and route, the delay will most likely be different.

The problem is, most FPGA engineers want to be precise and repeatable but the method you are proposing is somewhat chaotic and unreliable.